# How to rename a file in .NET?

Tags: file, rename, .net

Using `System.IO.File` or another `.NET` class, what is the best way to rename a file?

I want to be able to rename files on local drives or on network locations.

If using `System.IO.File`, is `Move` the best way?

Comment: An article that talks about what you're tying to do is *[How can I rename a file in C#?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/435a2692-6161-4039-bfa9-5e6211d90c49/how-can-i-rename-a-file-in-c)*.

Comment: How can this not be a duplicate 5 years after Stack Overflow launched?

Comment: @PeterMortensen closest match: [Rename a file in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218910/rename-a-file-in-c-sharp). Although in this case CJ7 is aware of that method (`System.IO.File`) As I read it, the question is if there is a better option that works across different drives and network locations. I haven't found clear statement if the mentioned API works in thoses cases (my intuition is that it does)... yet it is worth to mention some alternatives to rename and move file avalialbe in .NET not mentioned in the linked question.

Comment: Starting point: *[Rename some files in a folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680786/rename-some-files-in-a-folder)*

Comment: Other: *[Rename a file in C# (NET 2.0) without moving it or using DOS / Visual Basic commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688487)*

Answer (score 107):

---

### Alternatives

**System.IO.File.Move**

You can rename a file with `System.IO.File.Move` like this:

```
var sourcePath = @"C:\folder\oldname.txt";
var destinationPath = @"C:\folder\newname.txt";
File.Move(sourcePath, destinationPath);
```

You may be interested in keeping the same location and just change the name of the file. Sure that can be done:

```
var sourcePath = @"C:\folder\oldname.txt";
var newName = "newname.txt";
var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(sourcePath);
var destinationPath = Path.Combine(directory, newName);
File.Move(sourcePath, destinationPath);
```

---

**System.IO.FileInfo.MoveTo**

You can also use `System.IO.FileInfo.MoveTo`:

```
var sourcePath = @"C:\folder\oldname.txt";
var destinationPath = @"C:\folder\newname.txt";
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(sourcePath);
info.MoveTo(destinationPath);
```

*Note*: You can also build the destination path as shown above.

---

**"Hand move"**

Evidently you can always open the existing file, create a new one with the desired name... copy the contests from the old to the new one, and finally delete the old one. This will work given you have write access, although dates and security info (owner of the file, etc...) will not be preserved.

You can see an example of that at *the accepted solution of* [How to write contents of one file to another file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3914744/402022).

---

*Notes*

**Note 1**: Others alternatives include: `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem.Rename` and `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.RenameFile`.

Both `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem.Rename` and `System.IO.File.Move` are equivalent, they do parameter checks, permissions checks and error handling around [`MoveFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239(v=vs.85).aspx) from `kernel32`.

Regarding `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.RenameFile`, it will rename files in the same folder given the full path and the new name (similar to what I present above to build the destination path), and then fall back to `MoveFile` from `kernel32`.

In a similar fashion `System.IO.FileInfo.MoveTo` will call `MoveFile` from `kernel32`.

**Note 2**: It should also be noted that you cannot find `Microsoft.VisualBasic` from Mono. That means that `System.IO.File.Move` and `System.IO.FileInfo.MoveTo` are the only portable options.

---

### It is all MoveFile.

As mentioned above all those methods will fallback to `MoveFile` from `kernel32`. `MoveFile` will work for any mounted drive on the system (even network drives), although it should not be used to move from a volume to another. In that case it will be necessary to copy the file to the destination and remove the old file.

---

### The best alternative

Since the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem.Rename` and `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.RenameFile` may not be used in other operating systems as they are not ported by Mono, I'll discard those.

So, we are left with `System.IO.File.Move` and `System.IO.FileInfo.MoveTo`. Between those `System.IO.File.Move` has less overhead because it doesn't have to maintain the state of the `FileInfo` object. Other than that they will work the same... so, if you are already using `FileInfo` use `System.IO.FileInfo.MoveTo` otherwise `System.IO.File.Move`.

And so, **`System.IO.File.Move` is the best option to rename files in .NET!** (They didn't give us a whacky API).

*Celebrate!*